# How to create "page" used for generating PDF?

Tags: php, functions, routing

I am new to wordpress but I do have some knowledge base in php.

I am developing custom theme for my Wordpress site. I also have a PHP file which generates PDF file based on GET parameters and it's located in theme's root folder - let's say it's called generate-pdf.php. And I want to create a link in some part of my website which refers to the script like this: "http://my-wp-site.com/generate-pdf.php?a=1.

Is that possible without creating a page with slug "generate-pdf" in wp-admin and the page-generate-pdf.php?

I don't really want this script to be mentioned in administration.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your script need access to any WordPress API or data?

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a standalone script, you can just link to it directly and WordPress will be none the wiser. Just make sure you get the link right - if it's in your theme, it will be something like:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/generate-pdf.php
```

Don't hardcode the URL though, use the available template functions:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/generate-pdf.php">Generate!</a>
```

Of course if you want a "pretty" URL you can use [the rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).